# How do I properly wrtite this method out to get rid of the "missing @end" error?

Tags: objective-c, methods

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SuperHero.h"

                                                                      'missing @end'
@implementation Superhero : NSObject 


-(int)Fight:(int)enemyStamina{


    int resultingStamina = enemyStamina - 5;

    return resultingStamina;
}

@end
```

Comment: It looks fine to me.  Are you sure you've copypasted correctly?  Try Cmd+Shift+K.

Comment: Did you remember the `@end` in SuperHero.h?

Comment: Does that really produce the error in the `.m` and not in the `.h`?  Interesting.

Comment: Well that's extraordinarily silly and makes this question worth an upvote.

Comment: @nhgrif No it's not; that's how the pre-processor works.

Comment: I appreciate all of your help. I am a complete noob when it comes to programming. I'm trying to learn with a tutorial that is using this code, but when I put it into Xcode 5 or six, I still encounter this error. The .h is fine. I'm getting no errors there, as I DO, in fact, have the @end in there.I will try to build and clean and the cmd+shft+K trick and I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

This is valid code (syntax). Without header code I can't say more, but probably You miss  `@end` in header file. Also, try to clean and rebuild your project. 
Also, as kambala mentioned, specify inheritance with `@interface` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is specified only in the `@interface` section. So remove the `: NSObject` part in your code and you'll be fine.

Comment: After cleaning and rebuilding, I am still recieving the 'missing end' on the implementation line and I am also getting the 'missing end' after my end line. I have tried removing ": NSObject", as the tutorial I am using does not reference that. It seems like this is more of an XCode bug, but it would be nice if there were a way around it.